# Cannot make google ads position fixed

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, adsense

I am developing a small website with the help of Angular JS. I have placed two Google ads on a page one on top and another on the right sidebar. This is the link to my page http://sarathiblog.com/particle/particle-photon-intro.

I have created a custom directive to place the ad on my page

```
.directive('googleAdsenseSide', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    replace: true, 
    template:'<ins class="adsbygoogle" style="display:block; max-width:336px; max-height:280px" data-ad-client="ca-pub-XXXX"  data-ad-slot="XXXX" data-ad-format="auto"></ins>',
    controller: function () {
            //console.log("sarathiblog: Google Adsense is being added!");
        (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
    }
};
```

});

I use `<google-adsense-side>` tag to include the directive. When I tried to apply `style="position:fixed"` for the div enclosing the above tag.

```
<div style="position: fixed">
<google-adsense-side></google-adsense-side></div>
```

I get the following error while inspecting console.

```
angular.js:14525 
.   T
.   message : "adsbygoogle.push() error: No slot size for availableWidth=80" name : "TagError" stack : "TagError: adsbygoogle.push() error: No slot size for availableWidth=80↵    at se (http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js:1:28573)↵    at He (http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js:1:33384)↵    at If (http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js:1:52831)↵    at Gf (http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js:1:49334)↵    at Hf (http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js:1:49304)↵    at Sf (http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js:1:57455)↵    at Tf.c.client (http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js:1:55741)↵    at nc (http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js:1:11657)↵    at wc (http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js:1:14349)↵    at Object.Tf [as push] (http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js:1:55720)" __proto__ : Error
```

""

Comment: probably position fixed removes the ability for the ad to see the width and height? Maybe you can add position fixed and a fixed width and height too?